# ¿Habrá manera de depurar/mejorar este código?

Tags: angular, typescript

buenas noches tengo estas variables booleanas las cuales declaro para posteriormente usarlas en condicionales, mi pregunta habra manera de meterlas en una sola y solo declarlas de manera todo en conjunto en vez de uno por uno?

```js
 FiltroReporte1: boolean;
  FiltroReporte2: boolean;
  FiltroReporte3: boolean;
  FiltroReporte4: boolean;
  FiltroReporte5: boolean;
  FiltroReporte6: boolean;
  FiltroReporte7: boolean;
  FiltroReporte8: boolean;
  FiltroReporte9: boolean;
  FiltroReporte10: boolean;
  FiltroReporte11: boolean;
  FiltroReporte12: boolean;
  FiltroReporte13: boolean;
  FiltroReporte14: boolean;
  FiltroReporte15: boolean;
  FiltroReporte16: boolean;
  FiltroReporte17: boolean;
  FiltroReporte18: boolean;
  FiltroReporte19: boolean;
  FiltroReporte20: boolean;
  FiltroReporte21: boolean;
  FiltroReporte22: boolean;
  FiltroReporte23: boolean;
```

eso mismo pero con la condicional if ya que declaro uno por uno, habrá manera de mejorarlo?, lo que hace dependiendo del reporte seleccionado hago comparaciones con el if y luego muestro o no los input que tengo en el html.

```js
ReporteSeleccionado(): void {
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '1'){ this.FiltroReporte1 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte1 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '2'){ this.FiltroReporte2 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte2 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '3'){ this.FiltroReporte3 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte3 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '4'){ this.FiltroReporte4 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte4 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '5'){ this.FiltroReporte5 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte5 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '6'){ this.FiltroReporte6 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte6 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '7'){ this.FiltroReporte7 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte7 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '8'){ this.FiltroReporte8 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte8 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '9'){ this.FiltroReporte9 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte9 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '10'){ this.FiltroReporte10 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte10 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '11'){ this.FiltroReporte11 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte11 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '12'){ this.FiltroReporte12 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte12 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '13'){ this.FiltroReporte13 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte13 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '14'){ this.FiltroReporte14 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte14 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '15'){ this.FiltroReporte15 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte15 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '16'){ this.FiltroReporte16 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte16 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '17'){ this.FiltroReporte17 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte17 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '18'){ this.FiltroReporte18 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte18 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '19'){ this.FiltroReporte19 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte19 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '20'){ this.FiltroReporte20 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte20 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '21'){ this.FiltroReporte21 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte21 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '22'){ this.FiltroReporte22 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte22 = false; }
    if(this.reportes_exportar == '23'){ this.FiltroReporte23 = true; } else { this.FiltroReporte23 = false; }
  }
```

```html
<p-multiSelect *ngIf="FiltroReporte1 || FiltroReporte3 || FiltroReporte4 || FiltroReporte5 || FiltroReporte6 || FiltroReporte7 || FiltroReporte8|| FiltroReporte9 || FiltroReporte10 || FiltroReporte11
                || FiltroReporte12 || FiltroReporte13 || FiltroReporte14 || FiltroReporte19 || FiltroReporte20 || FiltroReporte21 || FiltroReporte22 || FiltroReporte23" styleClass="mb-2"
                 [options]="PeriodoEscolar" [(ngModel)]="m_periodo_escolar" defaultLabel="Seleccione un periodo escolar" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" selectedItemsLabel="{0} programas seleccionados" styleClass="mb-2"></p-multiSelect>
                <p-dropdown *ngIf="FiltroReporte1 || FiltroReporte3 || FiltroReporte19 || FiltroReporte20 || FiltroReporte21 || FiltroReporte22 || FiltroReporte23" [options]="TipoCurso" [(ngModel)]="m_tipo_curso" placeholder="Selecione un tipo de curso" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
                <p-dropdown *ngIf="FiltroReporte2 || FiltroReporte3 || FiltroReporte10" [options]="PlanEstudio" [(ngModel)]="m_plan_estudio" placeholder="Selecione un plan de estudios" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
                <p-dropdown *ngIf="FiltroReporte2 || FiltroReporte5" [options]="EstatusEstudiante" [(ngModel)]="m_estatus_estudiante" placeholder="Selecione un estatus para le estudiante" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
                <input *ngIf="FiltroReporte9 || FiltroReporte10" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="m_matricula" placeholder="Ingrese una matrícula" class="mb-2"> 
                <p-calendar *ngIf="FiltroReporte9 || FiltroReporte14 || FiltroReporte15" [(ngModel)]="m_rango_fechas" selectionMode="range" [readonlyInput]="true" inputId="range" placeholder="Elige un rango de fecha" styleClass="mb-2"></p-calendar>
                <p-dropdown *ngIf="FiltroReporte10" [options]="Beca" [(ngModel)]="m_beca" placeholder="Selecione una beca" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
                <p-multiSelect *ngIf="FiltroReporte14" [options]="TipoBaja" [(ngModel)]="m_tipo_baja" defaultLabel="Seleccione un tipo de baja" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" selectedItemsLabel="{0} programas seleccionados" styleClass="mb-2"></p-multiSelect>
                <p-dropdown *ngIf="FiltroReporte16 || FiltroReporte17 || FiltroReporte18" [options]="Configuracion" [(ngModel)]="m_configuracion" placeholder="Selecione una configuración de admisión" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
                <p-button *ngIf="FiltroReporte1 || FiltroReporte2 || FiltroReporte3 || FiltroReporte4 || FiltroReporte5 || FiltroReporte6 || FiltroReporte7 || FiltroReporte8|| FiltroReporte9 || FiltroReporte10 || FiltroReporte11
                || FiltroReporte12 || FiltroReporte13 || FiltroReporte14 || FiltroReporte15 || FiltroReporte16 || FiltroReporte17 || FiltroReporte18 || FiltroReporte19 || FiltroReporte20 || FiltroReporte21 || FiltroReporte22 || FiltroReporte23" 
                label="Generar reporte" icon="pi pi-download" iconPos="right"></p-button>
```

**Así lo hago mientras, pero es código en exceso, no sé si habrá manera de reducirlo?!**

Comment: Siempre que tengas varias variables con un nombre y probablemente también propósito común, es buena idea usar un arreglo como reemplazo de todas ellas. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `color1 = "Blanco", color2 = "Rojo", color3 = "Verde"` puedes escribir `color = [ "Blanco", "Rojo", "Verde" ]` y lo mejor es que puedes escalarlo a cualquier cantidad de elementos.

Comment: ya lo intente asi amigo, meterlo en una sola, pero me da error, mi pregunta es como declaro todas esas como que son booleanas y luego para usarlo en la condicional if??

Comment: No sé usar Angular, pero es probable de que haya alguna forma más cómoda de hacerlo. En algunas respuestas de Stackoverflow en inglés parecen sugerir `let elemento of arreglo` como valor del `ngFor`, no sé si sirva para `ngIf`. O quizá puedas usar una función que devuelva `true` o `false` en función a los valores del arreglo. Eso último si deberías poder hacerlo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58982631/13419694

Comment: gracias amigo lo checo, saludos

Comment: @oscarggh "lo intenté y me da error" no dice nada. Imagínate que alguien te dice "lo intenté así y me funcionó", ¿de qué te sirve? Si necesitas indicar cómo intentaste usar un arreglo, ve a [edit] y AÑADE el intento junto con los errores que te da al usar ese código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que no pusiste el código completo es imposible mostrar la solución exacta. Pero con el fin de ayudarte, tu código debería ver así

```
class AlgunNombre{
    FiltrosReportes : Array<boolean> = new Array();
    reportes_exportar :string="1"; //esto ni dea de donde viene

    constructor(){
        this.InitFiltros(23); //cantidad de filtros = 23
        
    }
    InitFiltros(num:number): void{
        for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
            this.FiltrosReportes.push(false);
        }
    }

    ReporteSeleccionado(): void { //esta función la llamas de algun lado
        let index=Number(this.reportes_exportar) -1;
        for(let  i=0;i<this.FiltrosReportes.length;i++){
            this.FiltrosReportes[i] = index==i;
        }
    }

    HayAlgunFiltro(): boolean{
        return this.FiltrosReportes.some(f=>f);
    } 

    HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(...ids:number[]) : boolean{
         return this.FiltrosReportes.some((f,i)=> {
            if(f && ids.includes(i+1)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
         });
```

Tal como te lo indicaron en los comentarios, crear un array de booleanos para almacenar los fitros.

Además 2 funciones:

- HayAlgunFiltro() que te retorna si alguno de ellos es true
- HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(ids:Array)  que le ingresas una array de numeros, que corresponden a la ID de los filtros en tú código antiguo, y te indica si de esos del array existe alguno true;

Luego en la parte html, no estoy seguro como se hace (muchos años que no veo angular), pero creo que debería ser algo como esto:

```
<p-multiSelect *ngIf="HayAlgunFiltro()" styleClass="mb-2" 
[options]="PeriodoEscolar" [(ngModel)]="m_periodo_escolar" defaultLabel="Seleccione un periodo escolar" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" selectedItemsLabel="{0} programas seleccionados" styleClass="mb-2"></p-multiSelect>
<p-dropdown *ngIf="HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(1,3,19,20,21,22,23)" [options]="TipoCurso" [(ngModel)]="m_tipo_curso" placeholder="Selecione un tipo de curso" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown *ngIf="HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(2,3,10)" [options]="PlanEstudio" [(ngModel)]="m_plan_estudio" placeholder="Selecione un plan de estudios" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value" [showClear]="true" styleClass="mb-2"></p-dropdown>

//...etc
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo yussef me quedo super con esa parte, de verdad aprecio tu tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: perdon que reabra la pregunta con este comentario men es que me da error en as funciones de los *ngIf="HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(2,3,10)" siempre me da error el segundo parametro dentro de los parentesis, au que se debera ?

Comment: @oscarggh cambié la función HayAlgunFiltroDeEstos(...ids:number[]), verifica ahora por favor

Comment: me funciono de verdad muchisimas gracias.

Comment: @oscarggh Que bueno!! Un gustazo